# Continuous and convex implies subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and convex. Show that u is subharmonic.

*My attempt*:

I used the convexity of f to write for $z \in \mathbb{C}, t \in [0,2\pi],r>0$ $f(z) \leq \frac{1}{2}(f(z-re^{it})+f(z+re^{it})) $

Taking integrals from 0 to $2\pi$ :

$2 \pi f(z) \leq \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}(f(z-re^{it})+f(z+re^{it}))dt$

How do I proceed so that I get something like:

$f(z) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}f(z+re^{it})dt $ ?

Comment: change variables $t \to t+\pi$ and use periodicity to show that $\int_0^{2\pi}f(z-re^{it})dt=\int_0^{2\pi}f(z+re^{it})dt$